# Moving a robot in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use the gazebo package to simulate a simple car-like robot moving around a field. Currently, I've been able to load a model of my robot into a simulation. However, I haven't had any luck understanding how to go about making the robot move via external commands (keyboard presses, etc.).

The documentation seems to gloss over this, or at least I can't find where it's described. How would I go about making a robot move in the a Gazebo simulation?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9628/moving-a-robot-in-gazebo/) by [ncw000](https://answers.ros.org/users/314/ncw000/) on ROS Answers with karma: 109 on 2011-04-03

Post score: 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can write a gazebo plugin to send torque or velocity commands to each wheel and the steering joint.  Possibly wrapping a simple PID controller around each controlled joint.  An [empty gazebo_plugin template](https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/trunk/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_template.cpp) has been provided for your convenience.  Also, please take a look at the [diffdrive example](http://ua-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/stacks/erratic_robot/trunk/erratic_gazebo_plugins/src/diffdrive_plugin.cpp) for reference on how to construct a plugin that sends velocity commands to individual joints.

Alternatively, if you are familiar with [pr2_mechanism control stacks](http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_mechanism), you can use some predefined [robot mechanism controllers](http://ros.org/wiki/robot_mechanism_controllers) to control your joints.  A simple controlled joint example can be found in [the single link example as shown here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_simulator/Tutorials/Pendulums).

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2011-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cybodroid](https://answers.ros.org/users/25023/cybodroid/) on 2015-12-27**:
The Link for empty gazebo plugin template doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In Gazebo, Stage and real-world navigation initiating movement usually involves some variant of the "cmd_vel" topic, which is based on the "Twist" message format. For simple testing there are a number of nodes in different stacks (turtlebot, pr2) that provide this function using keyboard commands, usually named something like "keyboard_teleop".

I suggest that you examine the turtlesim tutorial (http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingTopics) for a good start. It uses "rosrun turtlesim turtle_teleop_key". Use rxgraph to inspect the topics/messages in your simulation and be prepared to remap topic names as required.

---

Originally posted by [Bart](https://answers.ros.org/users/286/bart/) with karma: 856 on 2011-04-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ncw000](https://answers.ros.org/users/314/ncw000/) on 2011-04-09**:
I understand that movement commands take that format and how turtlesim uses keyboard_teleop, but I'm still not sure how to actually interact with the Gazebo robot simulation. Is there a specific topic to publish to, or some other method that causes the robot to move? Where do I send move data to?

**Comment by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on 2011-04-05**:
More about /cmd_vel and Twist Messages in car-like robots here -> http://answers.ros.org/question/585/cmd_vel-and-move_base

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-04-03**:
I would support adding a standardized car command interface to `common_msgs` somewhere. We should be able to get that into E-turtle if we did an API review some time soon.

**Comment by [Bart](https://answers.ros.org/users/286/bart/) on 2011-04-03**:
If an appropriate message type doesn't already exist, it is straighforward to create a new message type and topic name (eg - front_wheel_angle, drive_wheel_velocity as "cmd_car"). Appropriate tutorial is ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv. You still have to write some code at the receiving end to interpret this command.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-04-03**:
This is true and helpful, but keep in mind that Twist is not really a very useful or natural interface for car-like robots.

**Comment by [k2108](https://answers.ros.org/users/30550/k2108/) on 2021-08-09**:
There is a ros package called teleop_twist_keyboard (http://wiki.ros.org/teleop_twist_keyb...). This can be used to read from the keyboard and publish to /cmd_vel

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're still interested this two tutorials helped me a lot in a very similar problem. I use the pr2 controllers 'cause I don't have the time to make my own so I just build my own stats over the pr2. Hope it helps you:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_controllers/Tutorials/Using%20the%20robot%20base%20controllers%20to%20drive%20the%20robot

http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_controllers/Tutorials/Using%20the%20base%20controller%20with%20odometry%20and%20transform%20information

---

Originally posted by [Aidan1488](https://answers.ros.org/users/777/aidan1488/) with karma: 46 on 2011-07-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [abraham](https://answers.ros.org/users/39945/abraham/) on 2019-03-15**:
hey am doing the same thing in 2019 ,can help me out how do you implement pr2 controller on your model

**Comment by [raj199322](https://answers.ros.org/users/47159/raj199322/) on 2020-04-25**:
@abraham Hi, Even i am trying to develop similar model but no success as of now. Did you figure out any particular tutorial on this?